# Handling Nested Group Permisions (ASP.NET Role Provider)

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, roleprovider, active-directory-group, security-roles

We have a security module which, based on group/role membership, controls permissions to resources in ASP.Net. I've built a custom ASP.Net Role Provider that queries Active Directory for group membership and which is used by this module.

Security checking works as follows for each request (caching used in places for performance reasons but excluded from this list):

1. Query AD for list of users group memberships
2. Query database for a list of users and groups with access to the requested resource
3. Compare results from AD with results from the database.  If the user explicitly has rights or if a group that the user is in has rights then allow access, else don't.

The problem arises when we have nested groups.  Lets say we have two groups: *ParentGroup* and *ChildGroup*, where *ChildGroup* is a member of *ParentGroup* in Active Directory and where our user is a member of *ChildGroup*.  According to the logic above if we give *ChildGroup* access to a resource then then the user can access the resource too.

Now logically (to me anyways) if we give *ParentGroup* access to a resource then all members of it, and any sub groups and their members acquired recursively, should also be able to access said resource.  But instead, because of the way my logic works they can't access the resource.  Step 1 from the above list does not see *ParentGroup* it only see's *ChildGroup*, and Step 2 only see's *ParentGroup* and does not see *ChildGroup*.

So the question is, to make it work how I described it "Logically" should, where should I fix the problem, and is there some method that would work *better* then another?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak3kd03.aspx) method instead of querying AD directly.  I posted some sample code [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457715/finding-users-that-are-members-of-two-active-directory-groups) which might help.

Comment: My code used to work this way, but it wasn't accurate all the time.  Case in point: User connects to website and "IsInRole" returns false for group "A".  User is then added to group "A" but does not log out of their computer.  User visits the website again and "IsInRole" still returns false.  To avoid this issue we connect straight to AD to perform the check.