# 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941 (LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN) has performance problems?

Tags: performance, active-directory, ldap

LDAP searching has some built-in rules, one of which is the `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN`.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx):

> 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941   LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN This rule is limited to filters that apply to the DN. This is a special "extended" match operator that walks the chain of ancestry in objects all the way to the root until it finds a match.

They go on to say how it is intended for recursive searching, instead of going back and forth to the server:

> The LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN is a matching rule OID that is designed to provide a method to look up the ancestry of an object. ... Previously, applications performed transitive group expansion to figure out group membership, which used too much network bandwidth; applications needed to make multiple roundtrips to figure out if an object fell "in the chain" if a link is traversed through to the end.

They also say it has two obvious use cases:

- check if a user "user1" is a member of group "group1"
- find all the groups that "user1" is a member of

That being said, [many](https://web.archive.org/web/20170607042532/https://dunnry.com/blog/TransitiveLinkValueFilterEvaluation.aspx) [people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143665/single-line-ldap-query-that-enumerates-users-from-a-group-within-a-supergroup) [have](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/f238d2b0-a1d7-48e8-8a60-542e7ccfa2e8/recursive-retrieval-of-all-ad-group-memberships-of-a-user?forum=ITCG) [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534669/improving-recursive-active-directory-function) that in practice, using `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN` is much slower (in our case, a factor of 10x) than simply doing the recursive "member-of" search that the above quote says `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN` was intended to replace.

So, ***why* is the `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN` approach slower?**  Are we missing something?  Is there an edge case we don't cover?  Is there any reason ever in the world to ever use the `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN`, and why, if it's unnecessarily slow, isn't it fixed?

Comment: Have you actually benchmarked a filter that uses the `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN` OID vs recursive memberOf logic?

Comment: Interesting, the first blog has benchmarks near the bottom.

Comment: The documentation claims that using the filter will decrease the network traffic between the client and domain controller. And that is true, as the domain controller performs all processing on its side and expands DN attributes. Also it claims that the search may be CPU intensive and inefficient. To make an efficient search you need to undestand what's going on under the hood. I. e. dissasemble lsass on DC or inject a hook into it. It's pretty clear, that DC makes a search in it's Jet database (where AD is stored). A bunch of research is required here

Comment: @ChadSikorra Yes. Well, others on my team did, after I told them they were being silly, that there was NO WAY it could be faster to do the manual recursion.  Anyway, they consistently showed `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN` to take 2.5-3.5s while the handrolled version took 0.2-0.3s.

Comment: In case if you goal is to check if a user is a member of some group, look at tokenGroups attribute. May be the fastest approach

Comment: What does your complete filter/search options look like out of curiosity?

Comment: Ended up here checking my sanity. 50 group nested membership is taking 1.9 seconds using a chain search, or 0.2 seconds using looped recursion. Adding a base reduces chain search time, so it seems it grabs all groups in scope, then matches.

Comment: I'd say there is some bug in AD side, maybe in the way how AD interacts with Jet DB engine.
Mine case: AD has more than 100K+ groups, a specific AD group has **no** nested groups and 10 specific users only. LDAP query never finishes, dies on timeout even if  timeout is extended to infinity on client's side.